# How to configure gentics mesh instance with AWS storage?

Tags: gentics-mesh

Right now I am trying to setup Gentics Mesh in AWS Cloud. While exploring the software I came across a feature of Gentics Mesh to use AWS S3 as storage. It would be helpful if anyone can point me to a documentation or  any other info which helps me to understand the S3 configuration for Gentics Mesh.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The S3 Storage Provider of Gentics Mesh is not yet fully implemented and can't yet be used to store binary data.